# Python sklearn package (possible) incompatibility

Tags: python, package

When I import sklearn, this error occurs. I have been looking in numerous places
on how to fix it, but haven't found the solution. What is the cause of this problem, and how do you solve it?

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 406, in <module>
    if np_version < (1, 12, 0):
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()`

This is a list of the packages I have in my computer (OS: Windows 10):

cffi (1.9.1)
colorama (0.3.7)
cryptography (1.6)
cycler (0.10.0)
decorator (4.0.10)
entrypoints (0.2.2)
idna (2.1)
inflection (0.3.1)
ipykernel (4.5.1)
ipython (5.1.0)
ipython-genutils (0.1.0)
ipywidgets (5.2.2)
Jinja2 (2.8)
jsonschema (2.5.1)
jupyter (1.0.0)
jupyter-client (4.4.0)
jupyter-console (5.0.0)
jupyter-core (4.2.0)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
matplotlib (2.0.0b4)
mistune (0.7.3)
more-itertools (2.3)
mpmath (0.19)
nbconvert (4.2.0)
nbformat (4.1.0)
ndg-httpsclient (0.4.2)
nose (1.3.7)
notebook (4.2.3)
numpy (1.12.0b1+mkl)
opencv-python (3.1.0)
panda (0.3.1)
pandas (0.19.1)
pickleshare (0.7.4)
pip (9.0.1)
prompt-toolkit (1.0.9)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pycparser (2.17)
Pygments (2.1.3)
pyOpenSSL (16.2.0)
pyparsing (2.1.10)
python-dateutil (2.6.0)
pytz (2016.7)
pyzmq (16.0.2)
qtconsole (4.2.1)
Quandl (3.0.1)
requests (2.12.1)
scikit-learn (0.18.1)
scipy (0.18.1)
setuptools (20.10.1)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
six (1.10.0)
sklearn (0.0)
sklearn-contrib-lightning (0.4.0)
sympy (1.0)
tornado (4.4.2) 
traitlets (4.3.1)
wcwidth (0.1.7)
widgetsnbextension (1.2.6)
win-unicode-console (0.5)

Comment: See [this bug report](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7898).

Comment: Thank you @BrenBarn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced the same problem and found the solution here:
[https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7898](http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7898)

Basically you have to open the file C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py and change this: 
np_version < (1, 12, 0) to np_version[:2] < (1, 12)